# How to save string to text file with ASCII encoding in Windows store apps/WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying hard to save some string to a text file with **ASCII** encoding in a win8 app project. Below is some of the code snippet:

```
StorageFile myfile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt");
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(myfile, "abcd→1234");
```

But it ended with **UTF-8** encoding.

I've done lots of search online and found nothing.So my question is how to write string to text file with **ASCII** as the encoding. Thanks!

Comment: Well firstly, be aware that `→` is NOT an ASCII character... Anyway, only UTF8 and UTF16 is supported for Windows Store text files  as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Windows Store apps cannot use non-Unicode encodings. But if your string only contains characters with codepoints between U+00 and U+7F (0..127) then UTF8 and ASCII are identical, because UTF8 was designed to be ASCII-compatible.

So, just encode it as UTF8 and decode as ASCII.